# wordpress social login plugin returning ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT having NGINX for hosting and load balancing

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am using wordpress social login 2.3.3 and enabled yahoo, twitter and facebook. But in my infrastructure i am using nginx for hosting webpage and there is another instance of nginx used for load balancing the traffic. My domain is registered and i am using non-standard port for HTTPS.

My issue is when after entering the Yahoo credentials by credentials are getting successfully authenticated and when hauth.done=Yahoo gives me  sent an invalid response ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

As per the code in wsl 2.3.3 author has already taken care of non standard port. So the issue seems to be narrowed down to Nginx configuration.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly because of below wrong parameters posted in general

1. redirect_to
2. baseUrl

In general it means with respect to HybridAuth that you are not landed on right page.

As you said that you are using Nginx as loadbalancer and server. You need to check your server request attributes.

You should look for

1. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT
2. SERVER_PORT
3. HTTP_HOST
4. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST

There can be other parameters as well, with all these attributes plugin forms correct URL.

Hope that Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT is caused because your redirect url in developers.yahoo.com and redirect url in plugin does not match. Try to configure them identically.

Comment: i just checked the network logs on the chrome, it seems the PHPSESSID during start of session didnt persisted when hauth.done was replied by yahoo. So it seems to be PHPSESSID issue. You have any idea for same. I am trying to use set_session_cookie_params in my hauth storage php