# include rule file to along with force https setting in godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, godaddy-api

I'm using godaddy as hosting in its admin panel I have .htaccess file as shown below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I made settings to force it to https as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%(HTTP-HOST)%{Request-URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Can any one tell me where to place core.php in rule. My core.php is given as following

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );

require_once( "ccioo/Template/class.Page.php" );
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
if ( function_exists( "date_default_timezone_set" ) ) {
    date_default_timezone_set( "Asia/Taipei" );
}
$myPage = new Page();
$myPage->Output();
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

So what i want is that either i enter www.myfavouriteweb.com or https://www.myfavouriteweb.com it should redirect to https://www.myfavouriteweb.com

Comment: Are you wanting to force HTTPS? If not, this question isn't really clear.

Comment: @Adam yes I do want to force https

Comment: Is some like this what you want ? : `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%(HTTP-HOST)/core.php [L,R=301]`

Comment: @MTK i try it .

Comment: @MTK It is taking some time. but see my updated section of question plz. thank you

Comment: Ok. In this case your original `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%(HTTP-HOST)%{Request-URI} [L,R=301]` must working. But the question is you have one active SSL certificate for your host ? Because if not can't work

Comment: @MTK If you see i have a core.php too. how to include that in my final htaccess

Comment: So if I understand you need to redirect all your traffic to `https://your_site/core.php`. Is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryIndex` from apache

```
DirectoryIndex = core.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%(HTTP-HOST)%{Request-URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?original_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In this case you can use `$_GET["original_request"]` in your `core.php` If you need the original request

E.g.

`https://your_site.com/something`

Then in your core.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["original_request"])){
        //here your code
        echo $_GET["original_request"];
    }else{
        //if acces directly to https://your_site.com  (without 'something')
        echo "direct acces";
    }
?>
```

In this example `something` does not really exist in your server ... It are handled in `core.php`

Comment: Don't forget ... `core.php` in this example must be on the root of your http_folder ... or you can change relative path ... E.g  ´/your_folder/core.php´ ... remember ... this is relative to your public_http folder

Comment: blank page ... and sometimes says 'this page isn't working'

Comment: See my updated answer. You need (for testing) to replace your original `core.php` ... with mi example

Comment: should i put the echo too ?

Comment: Yes the eco is only for testing ... first you need to test if it work ok ... after that ... you can replace with code you want. But first you need to be sure if it working

Comment: it prints 'direct acces' in blank white page

Comment: SO IT WORK AS ESPECTED :)

Comment: Now you need to add your code ... instead echo ... you can put your original ... code

Comment: you mean i should put all the code of if statement in else too ? or just in the else statement ?

Comment: Not if ... to else ... Your original code from your original `core.php` But ...  you need also to understand what are you doing , because until here ... I can help

Comment: This page isn’t working www.site.com sent an invalid response.ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Comment: So in this case `ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT ` is a bug from your libary or template you use ... because withowt it work

Comment: if your template is `wordpress` you can see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165726/wordpress-social-login-plugin-returning-err-invalid-redirect-having-nginx-for-ho

Comment: or try to search on google or stackoverflow `err_invalid_redirect your_template_library_or_plugin_name`

Comment: thanks @MTK. your answer and instructions were helpful in finding the real answer. accepting this because it lead to actual answer.